# Why svg blur dosen't work in html or browser?

Tags: html, svg, user-experience, svg-filters

I'm using Figma editor and I tried to blur element, in the editor everything looks fine, then I export it into SVG. I see that there are  tags that should make my element blur `<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="16"/>`
But it dosen't work, look in the href.

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1uvhpg7/)

Dunno why it doesn't work. I also can not find information about it is there HTML reason or the browser.

Comment: Not sure anything supports the BackgroundImage pseudo input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert says, the main problem is that the generated SVG is using `in="BackgroundImage"` as an input to the filter.  No browsers support that feature AFAIK.

Instead of trying to blur the image, Figma's approach is to try to blur the background and blend it on top of the picture.

The filter can be rewritten to avoid using `BackgroundImage`.  You might want to file a bug with Figma about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to this bug report
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9081?page=com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities%253atransitions-summary-tabpanel
filters are not supported and I think developers can't fix the problem then they closed this bug

Comment: Why is that QT bug relevant to this question?  The OP didn't mention QT.